# SQL injection with malicious payload disguise in hexadecimal value

Tags: mysql, sql, hex, sql-injection

I am investigating in SQL injection and having a difficulty at hiding payload in hex, hope someone can advise.

For example, the injection:
select name from user where id= ? --> this where I want to inject

I want to make the query like:( just for example only)
select name from user where id= 1 union select 1,2,3

In order to hide my payload, I would like to convert "1 union select 1,2,3" into hexadecimal as below:
select name from products where id=X'3120756E696F6E2073656C65637420313233';
select name from products where id=0x3120756E696F6E2073656C65637420313233;

However, somehow mysql does not interpret my hex into the original string, but consider it as a number which is not logic in my point of view. Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: If that ? is the parameter of the query, you cannot do SQL Injection.

Comment: I know parameter will help preventing again SLQ injection, I am just curious how the hexa works

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly logical for MySQL to interpret both `0x3120...` and `X'3120...'` as *hexadecimal literal expressions* in both cases, and to interpret as a number, string, or blob, as context dictates.

The parser would not under any circumstance interpret such expressions ambiguously, any more than it would misinterpret something like this:

```
WHERE id = '1 UNION ALL SELECT ...'
```

It's unambiguously a literal string expression, the same as the two examples provided.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

I am not inclined to assist anyone with advice on how to exploit a SQL injection vulnerability.  Using urlencoding would allow you to pass something like `%31%20%75%6E...` which is really no clever exploit at all, only a different way of encoding a URL for presentation at an already-vulnerable interface and would serve no advanced purpose.  Either it's properly written, or it's already vulnerable without such a tactic, and such an encoding wouldn't change that except maybe in rare cases.